# How to stop TPose from being animated?

Tags: animation, armature

My [.blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0bKTHkpn7NZNmJqSTRudzlGcGM)

I have an armature that is linking to a **Walk** animation / action:
[image]

The problem arises when clicking play. It will start the animation from the TPose position, which causes deformation in the animation.

I've done this same exact process from exported `Mixamo` models where the action would automatically contour the mesh around the bones at the frame 1. However, it seems using a custom asset (model from unity's asset store or wherever) -- the TPose is still being used in the animation?

Comment: You can either remove the T pose keyframes in frame 1, and then move all keyframes 1 to the left in the dope sheet / graph editor , or use the NLA editor, and set the start frame there.  A lot of bvh files have the rest pose in frame 1 too. Not in a pos to write up a prop answer atm.

Comment: Oh, `bvh` files? I think that's my problem. This anim file is another `.fbx` that has its own armature, etc.. Ugh oh, maybe overlapping of bones? -- let me try your frame issue now

Comment: The NLA is the way to go imo as this will keep the tpose but not use it in animation.  However good NLA docs appear thin on the ground (hence this q http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64904/what-is-the-nla-editor-used-for)   The answer here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3736/how-should-an-animated-character-be-moved-while-repeating-a-walk-cycle .. .if frame 1 in walk action was a tpose could just set the repeated NLA strip to use  frames 2 to 48 of the action.

Comment: This is kind of weird. I cannot find any TPose keyframes -- [Here](https://i.gyazo.com/9defd2750878c90b959eb12062fa9bbf.png) is my NLA Editor. It seems like the TPose anim was merged with the new animation? But wait, TPose isn't supposed to be an animation?

Comment: Hit the n key to expand the properties. something like http://i.stack.imgur.com/W9CqT.png  Set the Action Extents start frame to 2... as  I still think the t-pose is just frame 1 of your Walk action.

Comment: Ty again bat, unfortunately no luck :P -- but when changing the extent start frame it actually manipulates the entire animation, is this normal? [Example](https://i.gyazo.com/31193886b60b9e83c13fddef492aa8af.gif) Seems like it's all one motion. Maybe it's the just the model got exported all glitchy hm. I'm going to play around with the animation data slide now. Forgot to press `n` :P

Comment: Your action has the pretty much the t pose at frame 2 (the start frame) and frame 31, and doesn't appear to be a walk cycle, would need to mirror it by the looks.  If you set it as the action in action editor and then check it out in graph editor.

Comment: @batFINGER Hm yeah, [I'm stumped](https://i.gyazo.com/e3a40e7bc0198d06e2d1d14bc440120f.png) lol.  Thanks for your help thus far though, most likely me not doing directions correctly. Fairly new to blender, will re-do the steps. :)

Comment: Did you guys even looked at @NiCk Newman file? The supposed T-pose is all over the animation. This animation starts from standard T-pose and continues with arms higher, plus it's only 1 half of a walk cycle. The way to fix it would be to copy all local X and Y values for all hands bones from frame 4 to frames 1-3, delete frames 26-28, duplicate 1-3 and place them instead of 26-28. Then copy pose and paste X flipped for every frame to make second half of the walk cycle. But it would need renaming all bones first, cause they don't have R. L., so Blender wouldn't copy-paste pose correctly.

Comment: @Mzidare Hmm. I think I'm doing this wrong or have a distorted .fbx file. Because the character comes with 10 + of these .fbx files which are all at different animations with no mesh. I need to apply the animation through the action editor above. I think something else inherently is going wrong that is a simple fix. I've done this exact same thing with mixamo models and it works fine. The TPose is still there but only when switched to `Pose` mode. Animating though, the TPose is not included, but on these models they are. Maybe how the author exported them is the culprit?

Comment: This is weird. Animation on the Armature and Walk are exactly the same, and yet Armature behaves differently. First time see something like this.