# How do I join to actions together (from the dope sheet and action editor) to form one animation?

Tags: animation, dopesheet, actions

These videos told me that I need to create actions in the dope editor to make multiple animations on one object. I want two objects' movements to be one animation. I tried animating the second object in the same action as the first, but that just messes everything up. Now I'm just going to animate them in different actions. When I finish that, how do I join them together as one animation?
[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64904/what-is-the-nla-editor-used-for

Comment: show us your blend file

Comment: @Chris , edited it into the post.