# How can I import an FBX with multiple animations?

Tags: animation, .fbx

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.  I have FBX files that I've successfully imported into Blender, and most of them have multiple animations embedded in the file, but when I import them, only the first animation is included.  How do I import all the animations?

Comment: All the animation will be imported. You can switch between them in the Dope Sheet>> Action Editor. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/actions.html#working-with-actions

Comment: Okay, I see how to switch between animations now.  This leads me to my next problem: I need Blender to play Animation 1 first, and then Animation 2.  How do I get Blender to play both animations, back to back?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64904/what-is-the-nla-editor-used-for