Is it possible to make make a longer animation from shorter clips?
Is it possible to make multiple shorter animations (like loops and transitions) and stitch them together as a longer animation? I often need to do loops in my animations (eg. walking or running), but copy/pasting keyframes feels pretty inefficient way of doing this. Is The picture below illustrates a similar concept from another program:


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64904/what-is-the-nla-editor-used-for
